# Which is correct? : Recommend some routes to take or to be taken

Tags: verbs

I would like to know which of the following sentences I created is correct. I first created the second sentence, but after googled, I found some sentences like the first.

> 1. This navigation system recommends some routes **to take** to (reach) your destination.
> 2. This navigation system recommends some routes (need) **to be taken** to (reach) your destination.

Comment: Both are correct. They're just constructed differently.

Comment: The bracketed 'need' should never be used (like that) in this case. The 'reach' is optional - I'm pretty much 50/50 on whether or not to use it.

Comment: You either recommend something or you need something. You don't recommend that you need something. Although it's possible you could suggest you need something or say that you need something.

Comment: “To be taken” is passive voice and should be avoided